# DAX - Trying to write a measure which needs a relationship that doesnt exist

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to calculate totals using a relationship which doesnt exist. I have the following anonymised tables:

Team

[image]

Eng

[image]

Job

[image]

Hours

[image]

My relationships are:

[image]

I want to calculate the total hours where Job.EngID = Hours.EngID AND Job.JobID = Hours.JobID, per team. What I want is:

[image]

I am part of the way there, but only if I want to show hours by engineer, not by team

```
HrsMeasure =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Hours[Hrs] ),
    FILTER ( Hours, Hours[EngID] = MAX ( Job[EngID] ) )
)
```

This gives me:

[image]

Is there anything I can do, without changing the data model/relationships?

See below the PBIX file:

```
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuiIgc_S9J5JhbgBkRFKyNPYNoxxNA?e=gZBhi2
```

Cheers for all help

Edit 1 - So I have tried using an inactive relationship between Jobs and Hours but I still get the wrong values. This is done using a concatenated column of JobID/EngID on both Jobs and Hours tables:

```
HrsMeasureUSERELATIONSHIPJobEng = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Hours[Hrs] ),
    USERELATIONSHIP(Hours[JobEng],Job[JobEng])
)
```

Hope someone can help me on this as its driving me bonkers!
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was to create concatenated columns for JobID/EngID on both the Hours and Jobs tables. Join these two columns using an inactive relationship, and then use a CALCULATE with a USERELATIONSHIP to activate the inactive relationship - this has done the trick:

```
HrsMeasureUSERELATIONSHIPJobEng = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Hours[Hrs] ),
    USERELATIONSHIP(Hours[JobEng],Job[JobEng])
)
```